# Can Swagger generate custom generic types?

Tags: c#, typescript, generics, swagger

Assume we have API return model in C#

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
  public T Result;
  public bool Success;
}
```

and returning `ApiResult<string>` object instance to client

so we have swagger generated model

```
ApiResult[String] {
  result (string, optional),
  success (boolean, optional)
}
```

which is incorrectly converted to typescript class using https://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/

```
'use strict';
import * as models from './models';
export interface ApiResultString {
    result?: string;
    success?: boolean;
}
```

Is it possible to generate output models with generics same as in input models?

Comment: I too would be interested in an answer to this

Comment: I also would be interested in the answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created issue on [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8194) on GitHub . You can support this feature there. Looks like currently it is not possible.